# .changePassword in SQLite. What algorithm?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I know (and saw in SO) that SQLite has standard encryption method in system.data.sqlie.dll for c#: .changePassword, but what algorithm of encrypt it is use? AES128? 192? DES?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately find the answer was hard (no info in official documentation) but I did it.

AES128.